# Examples of using model existence theorem to show inconsistency

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory, incompleteness

I have seen the model existence theorem many times used to show the consistency of a theory.  It works as follows. Let $T$ be a theory. A model $\mathcal{M}$ is given for $T$ and therefore, by the model existence theorem, $T$ is thereby known to be consistent.  My question is, does anyone have specific examples of the reverse direction used to prove that a theory is incomplete?  Specifically, I am looking for examples in the literature where it was unknown if $T$ was consistent or not.

That is, for a specifc theory $T$, first show directly that there are no models for $T$, and as a result conclude that $T$ is inconsistent.

Comment: You are confusing the completeness theorem and the soundness theorem. The soundness theorem is what allows one to conclude that if a model of a theory exists, the theory is consistent. The completeness theorem is the other direction. It is possible to use the completeness theorem to show a theory is inconsistent by proving it has no models, but one would be using the soundness theorem to show a theory is consistent by showing it has a model.

Comment: One can construct many artificial examples is that what you want?

Comment: @MarkSaving, what do you mean?  Model existence:  if $T$ is syntactically consistent, that is for no $s$ does $T$ does prove $s$ and $\neg s$, then $T$ has a model.  I am looking for the contrapositive of that. I wish to prove $T$ is inconsistent. By the contrapositive form of the model existence theorem, if $T$ has no models, then $T$ is syntactically inconsistent.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, I am looking for non-artificial examples, where this technique was used. For example Kunen showed ZFC + “$\exists$ non-trivial elementary embedding from $V\hookrightarrow V$“ was inconsistent. I don’t know the details of that proof, but it was a proof showing that some theory $T$ was inconsistent. I am asking for proofs in the literature showing that $T$ is inconsistent using the contrapositive form of the model existence theorem.

Comment: @Eoin I agree with what you said in your comment. The error was when you stated, “ I have seen the model existence theorem (completeness theorem) many times used to show the consistency of a theory.” What you actually describe over the next three sentences is the use of the soundness theorem, *not* the completeness theorem.

Comment: @MarkSaving OK, thank you for the comment. I have deleted the reference to completeness theorem.

Comment: *"Let $T$ be a theory. A model $\mathcal{M}$ is given for $T$ and therefore,* **by the model existence theorem,** *$T$ is thereby known to be consistent."* still doesn't make any sense! This doesn't agree with the statement of model existence that you give in your above comment. As Mark says, this is the soundness theorem, which is qualitatively much easier to prove than model existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that nearly every proof of the inconsistency of a theory works the way you are describing.  It's very rare to see someone actually exhibit a sequence of formal sentences built according to the rules of a formal proof system and that ends in $s \wedge \neg s$ for some statement $s$.

You mentioned Kunen's proof of the inconsistency of the theory $T =  $ ZFC+"there is a non-trivial elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$".  A formal syntactic proof of this would be a nightmare.  Instead, Kunen argues that there are no models of the theory (the proof begins by assuming that you have an elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$, where $V \models ZFC$, that is, it starts with a model of $T$).  When he reaches a contradiction he concludes that the assumed elementary embedding did not exist, thus showing that there are no models of $T$.  It's still a proof by contradiction, as non-existence proofs often are, but it's very far from being a syntactic derivation of $s \wedge \neg s$ in a formal proof system.